# Jpeg files won't work as drawable resources - png files work fine

Tags: android

I am trying to use a background image... when I place the file.png in the drawable folder, eclipse recognizes it and everything works.

However, file.jpg doesn't work.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to resolve this?

I know it must work because in the docs it said the drawable resource can be a jpeg file also.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console or is it just silently not recognized as a drawable resource?

Comment: strange... now it works... but with new jpg file... the other ones I had been trying last night didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is to clarify the issue for the other beginners out there that are running into this. This appears to be a rampant issue that gets most beginners and wastes a ton of time. Just google "eclipse load drawable" and look at all the people having trouble. They all end with "well, it works now but I don't know why...".

I've had the same issue on two different projects over the last couple days. There does appear to be an issue (undocumented feature?) with Eclipse. First, make sure the filename is in all lowercase. This wasn't immediately clear to me until i read [a-z1-9_.] about a hundred times. It does NOT in fact say [a-zA-Z1-9_.].

Second you need to restart Eclipse after adding drawable images to a project. Eclipse will not build the drawable resources during it's normal operation. The example of this is to simply add an image (png or jpg) and manually build the project. No matter how many times you build or clean the project, the images will not show up in /bin/res/drawable. Now save your project and click File->Restart. Auto-magically the images are in the bin folder, can be referenced using @drawable/, and do not cause build errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Eclipse, so for all I know this is a bug.  It's certainly a misfeature for Eclipse to not share with you the (always very helpful, in my experience) error output from`aapt`.  However, these may apply:

1. Although the file extension appears to be .jpg in Windows, it isn't really.  I understand from SO that case matters here, when it usually doesn't in Windows.  Verify the extension in cmd.exe or in right-click properties.
2. You have both a file.png and a file.jpg -- that is, they have the same name (here, "file") before the dot. The names must differ.
3. You have some invalid characters in the name.  Invalid, not to windows, but to `aapt` -- again, it would tell you exactly what it allows if you saw the error.  IIRC, valid characters are [a-z1-9_.].

Comment: thanks for the info. about the 2 files: I don't have them in the same directory at same time, first I tried the jpg. Didn't work. So then I replaced it with a png. filename is definitely valid, all my resources are like that... lowercase letters and _ only

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your jpeg image size or resolution is higher than the noramal size. Try to resize or change the resolution of particular image.